# WCF Service Slow To Pass Objects. Is That Normal?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-services

I've got a WPF application written in C#.  It has to instantiate thousands of objects.  After pulling data from the database server,  it has to run a ton of calculations that takes time.  The whole process takes up to 20-30 seconds with 80% of it coming from the calculations.

So to help resolve this issue, I wrote a WCF service that keeps a copy of the already instantiated objects with the calcs already run, and then upon request, transfers the instantiated objects to the calling client.

It works!  However it's slow...really slow.  Much slower than the original way.  It takes 3-4 minutes to transfer all the objects from the WCF service, thus defeating it's purpose.

I've tried streaming instead of buffering the service and increasing or decreasing the different service options in the client and server config files, but haven't found settings that make a real difference yet.

Is this slow speed to be expected, or should it be fast and I just need to modify some options?  If so, what options?

Comment: It could be down to serialization. What protocol endpoints are you using? And how 'big' are the objects?

Comment: I use BasicHTTPBinding.  The objects are serialized with the [Serializable] attribute.  The total size of all the object are about 350 MB.

Comment: My recommendation with WCF is to only pass the data needed across the wire. Because of this, I often work with `DTO` or `POCO` objects which just contain raw data to keep the data going to/from WCF as small as possible. WCF is going to be slower than running items locally since it has to go to the server and get its data, not just pull it from memory. What sort of calculations are you running that you can't just store the result of the calculation on the object itself?

Comment: If this is all happening 'internally' (i.e. not a web service) it might be worth trying to use sockets or named pipes as this serializes your objects to binary rather than XML/text.

Comment: Yes what @Rachel says too. Make sure you only serialize values that you need to transmit and maybe create lightweight objects if you can.

Comment: From the clients perspective, it can get the data from the database or from the WCF service.  Either way, all that data is getting passed over the network.  So, it seemed odd to me that if it comes from a WCF service it'll be over 10x slower than if it's coming from the database, but maybe WCF is just really slow in comparison.  The results of the calculations are stored in the objects, but they have to get calced each time which takes a while.  But the WCF service passes the already finished the calcs. I can take a different approach to this, but first want to see if it's necessary to do so.

Comment: Yeah, I can take a different approach like only passing the calc results.  I was just surprised about the findings that passing 350MB of data from a database is over 10x faster than passing 350MB of objects over WCF.  Certainly serialization would have overhead, but that just seemed like a lot of overhead to me.  But maybe not.  Thanks Dave and Rachel.

Comment: XML over WCF is a lot bigger than, SqlServer via DataReader for example.

Comment: I guess that's the crux of the problem.  But it's why I'm here asking.  Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF isn't necessarily slow but if the application isn't designed properly, the application can be slow. It could be compared to loading up a few thousand pounds of weight on a sports car. The car **is** a fast car, but it isn't really being used properly.

First, I would say you have to minimize the amount of data that is being sent on the wire (more about this later). Once on the wire, you'll get a lot better performance if you use TCP or named pipes instead of HTTP. See [Choosing a Transport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx). HTTP is easy since most networks are configured to let is past easily but it isn't designed for large data sets.

If the delay is coming from the calculations, then the only thing the WCF service will accomplish is offloading the processing from the server to the client. Ultimately this might be a good thing - or even necessary - if you plan on having a high volume of concurrent requests to the server but as you have noticed, it doesn't necessarily mean shorter times for the end user. What you should focus on doing is minimizing the calculation time.

It is hard to give specifics since you havent revealed much about what is being queried, what is being returned and the the calculations are doing. However, I have had impressive results with large data sets by offloading code from the application server to the database server via [Visual Studio SQL Server Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84b1se47%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Since .NET and MSSQL are both written on the CLR, you can write native database objects (like [user defined functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) in C# or VB or any other CLR language and deploy them directly into the database. Then you can use these functions in your queries and they are *very* fast since they are compiled into native SQL. I've seen orders of magnitude in difference between running C# in the application vs running the same function in the database.

Comment: Thanks! I was considering going the CLR route. The thing with my approach is that the calcs are already run. So, even if the server took 20 min to run the calcs, it doesn't matter because they're already done and the service has cached the objects. So, when a client says "give me the objects", the server doesn't have to reinstantiate them or rerun the calcs since that's already done. Instead the server just says "Sure, here they are". Unfortunately, that took almost 5 min for it to say. I can try the TCP or named pipes route, but I need it to be orders of magnitude quicker. Would it be? Thx!

Comment: Sorry, I can't be sure if the TCP/named pipes will be orders of magnitude faster. Do the clients really need all of the information at once or can you progressively load it? (via paging or "infinite scroll" or something else)

Comment: I've got different options on how to handle it.  This one required the least amount of re-architecturing and fit most nicely with the current design.  But there's definitely other options.  Just wanted to make sure this speed issue wasn't something easily fixable by changing a setting.  I'll check out the tcp/named pipes route though.  Thanks for the help

Comment: I echo what @Jeff says here. I have a web application where the server connects to a WCF service which returns 50k+ records from a database, does some calc and builds some summaries using linq. The pages served up however have the list paged and no more than 25 records at a time are loaded to the client. Response times are sub 1 second even under load. EDIT: That's a bit misleading, the database returns 0-50k+ and the service returns 1K records sub 1 second

Comment: Just implemented it with NetTCPBinding.  Definitely much faster, but still slower than instantiating it on the client side and letting the client do the calcs.  Oh well.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: @Nullqwerty Just curious, how much faster was it?

Comment: It brought it down to about a minute.  So, instead of 3-5 minutes, it was just 1.  However, not using the service but redoing all the calcs was under 30 seconds, so...  But, anywhere I'm currently using HTTP, I'm going to redo with TCP after seeing these results.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If 80% of your applicatiion's work comes from the calculations, then it might be a great idea to parallize some parts of it, for example with the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

Comment: Thanks!  Yep, implemented PLinq where I could last week, which was a major improvement in speed.  Thanks for the tip though!